# Query to search items with image

Tags: maximo

I am looking for a query to look for items that have a image.

```
(status != 'OBSOLETE' and itemsetid = 'ITEMSET1') and (exists (select 1 from dbo.inventory where ((location = 'SPARES')) and (itemnum=item.itemnum and itemsetid = item.itemsetid))) and (itemnum in (select imglib.refobjectid from IMGLIB where refobject='ITEM'))
```

everything works perfectly with the exeption when adding:

```
itemnum in (select imglib.refobjectid from IMGLIB where refobject='ITEM')
```

I can't reach the db so i can't check the contents of the IMGLIB table but AFAIK this should work?
refobjectid is the stored itemnum?

What am i missing?

Comment: Not much help can be given if you "can't reach the db". what do you expect as answer? The reader on stackoverflow has less knowledge about your db than you (should) have.

Comment: Every maximo db structure is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at [Maximo version 7.6.0.3 Entity Relationship Document (ERD)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/maximo-version-7603-entity-relationship-document-erd):

(part of) MAXIMO INCOMING RELATIONSHIPS for `IMGLIB`

| Name | source | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IMGLIB | ITEM | Relationship to the IMGLIB table, used to find the image for a given item. (imglib.refobject='ITEM' and imglib.refobjectid=:item$ITEM.ITEMID). The resulting set will contain zero or one object. |

I think you need `ITEMID`, and not `ITEMNUM`

(But I do not have knowledge of MAXIMO ... )

Comment: Hey Luuk, Thanks for helping! See https://interprosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/Where_Clause.png of where i need to add the query. I am running the query on the ITEM table and fetching if a record is made in the IMGLIB. If i change the query to itemnum = 'a working number' then it works perfectly. So refobjectid might not be the right column of the itemid.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like this:

```
   itemid in (
      select refobjectid from imglib where refobject='ITEM'
   )
```